# How to convert 8-char string to a 64-bit bigint and vice versa?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

Is there a simple way to convert a 8-character string (`char(8)`) to a 64-bit `bigint` ? (With a SQL statement).

And how to convert back from such a `bigint` to `char(8)`?

For example: **`'ABCDabcd'`** should become **`0x4142434461626364`** ('A'=65=0x41, 'B'=66=0x42, etc)

The string will always fulfill these criteria:

- it will always be encoded in CP1 codepage
- it will always be 8 characters long (filled with spaces)
- is will use only the characters between between 32 and 127 (0x20 to 0x7F)

It is very important that the conversion is 100% exact and deterministic. The encoding should always deliver the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this:

```
-- CHAR(8) variable
DECLARE @char8 CHAR(8) = 'ABCDabcd'

-- use BINARY_CHECKSUM, should be safe with a CHAR(8) 
DECLARE @checkInt64 BIGINT = BINARY_CHECKSUM(@char8)

-- use CAST(... AS BINARY(8)), should be safe with a CHAR(8)
-- note: cannot cast directly from CHAR to INT/BIGINT
DECLARE @charBinary BINARY(8) = CAST(@char8 AS BINARY(8))
DECLARE @binaryInt BIGINT = @charBinary

SELECT @char8, @checkInt64, @charBinary, @binaryInt
-- output: ABCDabcd, 1450341456, 0x4142434461626364, 4702394921898894180

-- VARBINARY/BIGINT can be casted back to the CHAR as well:
SELECT CAST(CAST(@binaryInt AS BINARY(8)) as CHAR(8)), CAST(@charBinary AS CHAR(8));
-- output: ABCDabcd, ABCDabcd
```

`BINARY_CHECKSUM` would fit into an Int64 at this length, but will be one way only.

`BINARY` will give you the exact hex you want, and should fit into bigint as well, and should be convertable back.